# How to get the selected e-mails in Outlook via Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I've code for Excel. It refers to an Outlook folder and loops the items. It picks each item of folder items and chooses the needed ones by parameters.

I want to work with Outlook Selection. User chooses mails in Outlook and presses a button on Excel.

I tried to determine variable as Outlook.Selection directly like

```
Public myOlSel As Outlook.Selection
```

It returns an error, because I need to switch settings to Outlook object model - but I'm writing a tool for users to only press the button to start macros.

When I determine variable myOlSel as Object and try to set it as Selection of Outlook application object it also doesn't work.

```
Set myOlSel = olApp.Selection
```

```vb
Sub CheckEmailsSelected()
    Set olApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    Set olNameSpace = olApp.Session '.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
    Dim att As Object
    If Param3 = 1 Then
    Set myOlSel = olApp.Selection
    
    For Each mItem In myOlSel.Items
    If mItem.Unread = True Then
        If DateValue(mItem.LastModificationTime) >= DateValue(Now) Then
            If mItem.Attachments.Count > 0 Then
            
            count4 = count4 + 1
    
            Set att = mItem.Attachments
            For i = 1 To att.Count
            If Right(att.Item(i).Filename, 4) = "xlsx" Or Right(att.Item(i).Filename, 3) = "xls" Then
            count5 = count5 + 1
            ReDim Preserve Stat(10, count5)
            Stat(1, count5) = mItem.LastModificationTime
            Stat(2, count5) = mItem.Companies
            Stat(3, count5) = mItem.Subject
            Stat(4, count5) = mItem.Sender
            Stat(5, count5) = mItem.SenderEmailAddress
            Stat(6, count5) = att.Item(i).Filename
            If Right(att.Item(i).Filename, 4) = "xlsx" Then Stat(7, count5) = Path2 & "\" & "Temp" & "\" & Right(mItem.EntryID, 24) & "-" & i & ".xlsx" Else Stat(7, count5) = Path2 & "\" & "Temp" & "\" & Right(mItem.EntryID, 24) & "-" & i & ".xls"
            Stat(8, count5) = mItem.Unread
            Stat(10, count5) = mItem.EntryID
            
            If Right(att.Item(i).Filename, 4) = "xlsx" Then att.Item(i).SaveAsFile Path2 & "\" & "Temp" & "\" & Right(mItem.EntryID, 24) & "-" & i & ".xlsx" Else: att.Item(i).SaveAsFile Path2 & "\" & "Temp" & "\" & Right(mItem.EntryID, 24) & "-" & i & ".xls"
            
            End If
            Next i
            
            End If
        End If
    End If
    Next mItem
    
    End If
    
End Sub
```

How can I get Outlook Selection from Excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub CheckEmailsSelected()
    Dim olApp As Object, m As Object
    Set olApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    
    Set myOlSel = olApp.ActiveExplorer.Selection
    For Each m In myOlSel
        If m.Class = 43 Then ' olMail = 43
            Debug.Print m.Subject
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Works, thank you, my error was -  I've tried to use  used  .Items method  for Selection, but it doesn't support it